# Crypto.PublicKey RSA Keysize off by one?

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to write a simple python method using Crypto.PublicKey.RSA that returns the size of an RSA public key, but the number returned is always the number I expect minus 1.

For example I give it a 1024-bit key and the number I get back from the size() function is 1023. I give it a 768-bit key and the number I get back is 767.

What am I missing here?

Results of the code below:
    **I would expect this to return 1024: 1023**

POC Python2 code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from base64 import b64decode

def computeRSAStrength(pubkey,verbose=None):
    """Compute and return RSA key strength given a public key"""
    #TODO: add base64 validation on pubkey

    #Format key and use python crypto libs to determine key strength
    keyDER = b64decode(pubkey)

    try:
        #IMPORTANT PART
        keyPub = RSA.importKey(keyDER)
        keySize = int(keyPub.size()) #+ 1 ??? WHY DOES THIS RETURN (expected - 1) ???
        #END IMPORTANT PART

    except ValueError, e:
        if verbose:
            print 'ValueError Exception: {}'.format(e)
        keySize = 0

    # ALTERNATE METHOD?: use import os and make a syscall to openssl

    if verbose:
        print ' - Key in PEM format:'
        print keyPub.exportKey('PEM')

    return keySize


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print 'I would expect this to read 1024: '+str(computeRSAStrength('MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBA'+
        'QUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDLM0fpK/rhklYDRJSBQ6bSyZKjQxTeEnZywzodwGAjAste2aOQzXJyZmZrjHZ'+
        '0JL6Gy/e351n1P0Yo0cVE4nEQ7WD9jo0cqVEmkf1SInnhN1FGX/pOTjrjh7QU398YFxks/rqnX6C1q'+
        'doeu7B4wwRhNEHUjlaH79afYqOtk0ta0wIDAQAB'))
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that `_RSAobj.size()` refers to the actual size of the key. It's a bit vague but the documentation for [size()](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.PublicKey.RSA._RSAobj-class.html#size) states this:

```
size(self)

Tell the maximum number of bits that can be handled by this key.

Returns:
    int
Overrides: pubkey.pubkey.size
    (inherited documentation)
```

I'm unsure, but it might actually mean the maximum number of plaintext bits that can be handled by crypto operations (although you can encrypt up to 128 bytes/ 1024 bit of plaintext). The code explicitly subtracts one from the number of bits in the modulus, so it is safe to add one to `size()` to get the modulus size.

There is some seemingly related information at https://security.stackexchange.com/q/44702.

Comment: Forgive me I'm new :( -- per that link you posted: with the padding done by RSA wouldn't the max number of bits that can be handled be less than keysize-1? Is there an easier way to get the keysize in python other than making a syscall to the openssl cli or using another 3rd party library?

Comment: Just use `key.size() + 1`. As I said, the pycrypto source code explicitly subtracts one in the `size()` function, but elsewhere it adds 1 (in `_RSAobj.__repr__()` for example).